# Asp is not honoring the defaultRedirect set within web.config, View Engines are breaking on finding other Error Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In our application we have an error page that is supposed to capture all errors in the application.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Content/Error.html" />
```

This Error page essentially spits *"An unexpected error has occured, please contact support with the following code : $HASH"*. Where $HASH (which is set as a cookie value) represents an ID that points to the captured exception within a log.

Yet when we look up the hash and data for some of our application errors, we find the following.

```
Exception information:
   Exception type: InvalidOperationException
   Exception message: The view 'Error' or its master was not found or no view 
engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
SomeLocation\Error.spark
Shared\Error.spark
SomeLocation\Error.shade
Shared\Error.shade
~/Views/SomeLocation/Error.aspx
~/Views/SomeLocation/Error.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Error.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Error.ascx
~/Views/SomeLocation/Error.cshtml
~/Views/SomeLocation/Error.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Error.vbhtml
  at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context)
  at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
  at <<More Internals>>
```

Meaning that ASP is trying to use any view engines to display our original error, Throw its own error, Trash our original error.

I **Expect** our original application exception to be logged. Not what is shown above. I do not expect Asp to be looking anywhere other than `~/Content/Error.html` to present errors.

**Quick fixes that I have tried**

- Set the `customErrors` `defaultRedirect`to a location that the ViewEngines Look into as well. Result : Everything Breaks
- Create a view and controller in a location that the view engines can use and redirect to the location set within `web.config`. Result : Error hash gets lost because the cookie data isn't being set.

Comment: is the application running on IIS?

Comment: @obl yup. IIS Express

Comment: check `FilterConfig.cs`, do you see `filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());`?

Comment: We have a `GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new AppInsightsHandleErrorAttribute())` located in a helper method to Application_Start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding

```
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ExceptionTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web">
  <EnableMvcAndWebApiExceptionAutoTracking>false</EnableMvcAndWebApiExceptionAutoTracking>
</Add>
```

to `ApplicationInsights.config`

Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/issues/921

Source: [AiHandleErrorAttribute Vs. Built-In auto added Action Filter provided by Application Insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51548243/aihandleerrorattribute-vs-built-in-auto-added-action-filter-provided-by-applica)

Comment: Wow! Did a dev deploy with that AppInsights update, we're repro'ing the errors that we need. 

I'm blown away that this is an Application insights bug. An upvote is not enough, many many thanks!

Comment: For follow up, how were you familiar with this bug?

Comment: @FinnM Honestly I just googled your exception message along with 'AppInsights'! Glad I could help and good luck.